# Convert code from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

My code exist some things like "< i585 >". I wan to get string from "i" to ">". And replace "585" instead of "< i585 >".   I write some code in JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var foo ="M <i585> <i646>";

while (foo.indexOf("<i") != -1) {

    var indexBaş = foo.indexOf("<i");

    var indexSon = foo.indexOf(">", indexBaş);

    var id = foo.substring(indexBaş + 2, indexSon);

    foo = foo.substring(0 , indexBaş) + id + foo.substring(indexSon + 1 , foo.lenght);

}
document.write(foo);
</script>
```

But I have to convert this code to php.
So I write this code

```
$foo ="M <i585> <i646>";

$start = 0;
$kacTane= 0;

for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($foo) ; $i++ ) {
    if($foo[$i] == "<") {
        if(($foo + 1 )< strlen($foo)) {
            if($foo[$i+1] == "i") {
                $kacTane++;
            }
        }

    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < $kacTane; $i++) {
    $ilkIndex = strpos($foo , "<" , $start);

    $sonindex = strpos($foo , ">" , $ilkIndex);

    $id = substr($foo , $ilkIndex + 2 ,( $sonIndex -3) - $ilkIndex  );

    $first = substr($foo , 0 , $ilkIndex +2);
    $second = substr($foo , $sonIndex + 1 , strlen($foo) - $sonIndex - 1 );

    $foo = "$first$id$second";
    $start = ($sonindex + 1);

}
echo $foo;
```

But it isn't work.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: You could make your life easier by creating an array (split on space) and do `foreach()`. If needed you can convert the array back to string afterwards.

Comment: I have no time to figure out code now but it sounds like you want to use preg_replace at some point. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Thank you. But the string can be "M<i656><i578>". I have to find another way.

Comment: Change your question and list correct examples otherwise people will not be able to help.

Comment: you are using a `for`-loop but not using or increasing `$i` anywhere. Does this function actually stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some pregmatch?

```
$foo ="M <i585> <i646>";
preg_match_all('/<i(.*?)>/',$foo, $results); //search for all numbers

$patterns = array();
$replace = array();
foreach ($results[1] as $result){
  $patterns[] = '/<i'.$result.'>/';
  switch ($result) {
    case '585':
      $result = '333';
      break;
    case '646':
      $result = '444';
      break;
  }
  $replace[] = '<i'.$result.'>';
}

$replace = preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $foo); //if you just want to repleace then this single line (+ arrays) are all you need.
echo '<br>'.$replace;
```

Answer (score 1):

There were some typos with the variable names ($sonindex - $sonIndex).

You remove 3 chars from the original string, then before the next iteration you add plus one to the $start, but you should substract one.

```php
$foo ="M <i585> <i646>";
$start = 0;
$kacTane= 0;

for($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($foo) ; $i++ ) {
    if($foo[$i] == "<") {
        if(($foo + 1 )< strlen($foo)) {
             if($foo[$i+1] == "i") {
                $kacTane++;
            }
        }

    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < $kacTane; $i++) {
    $ilkIndex = strpos($foo , "<i" ,$start);

    $sonIndex = strpos($foo , ">" , $ilkIndex);

    $id = substr($foo , $ilkIndex + 2 , $sonIndex  - $ilkIndex -2  );

    $first = substr($foo , 0 , $ilkIndex );
    $second = substr($foo , $sonIndex + 1 , strlen($foo) - $sonIndex - 1 );

    $foo = $first.$id.$second;
    $start = ($sonIndex - 1);
}
echo $foo;
```